# How do I add the following private frameworks to my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to add the following frameworks in my iPhone app:

- graphicsservice
- coretelephony
- celestial
- layerkit

But I cant found these frameworks in the list within Xcode. I tried to add them through "add >>> existing framework." but they weren't there.

Where are these and how can I add them to my iPhone app project?

Answer (score 0):

All these framework are not public framework but these are private framework.So add them by searching through private framework.

Add->Existing Framework->private framework

Comment: thanks raaz for ur reply.


But i cant see this "private framework" option anywhere.

where is it???/

Comment: step 1 :Right Click over your Framework Folder.

step 2 :click on Add

step 3 :click on Existing Frameworks

step 4: by default you must see the public framework provided by Apple

Step 5:Now at top of screen Above your frameworks 3 tab buttons are present to show how you want to see the folder(Choose the last one)

Step 6:Now you can see a folder Private frameworks below Frmaeworks

Otherwise you can navigate from 

Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOSplatform->Developer->SDKs->iPhone3.0.SDK->System->Library->PrivateFrameworks

Comment: But avoid using private framework in your application because apple may reject your applicaion.

Comment: @ raaz
thanks mate

i found most of the framework,except "layerkit". This framework is not there for me.Now how should i procide?

Any other way to avoid these framework,if apple finally gonna reject it,for using private framework.??

i m a dice application..which shoud rotate ,have to provide 3d animations and all..

so wat should i do before proceeding further??

thanks again

Comment: @shisir ,I have never tried 3d animation, but it is not impossible.You can try or search for OpenGL/OpenGLES/CoreAnimation for these things.

Comment: Now if you find your solution then check it as answered